# Making new Monad Cont with ContT Constructor

Tags: haskell

I started to read [The Mother of All Monads](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2008/12/mother-of-all-monads.html), and typed out this example:

```
import Control.Monad.Cont

ex1 = do
  a <- return 1
  b <- return 10
  return $ a+b
```

But I got a compile-time error:

```
ghci> :l ContMonad.hs 
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( ContMonad.hs, interpreted )

ContMonad.hs:4:4:
    No instance for (Monad m0) arising from a do statement
    The type variable ‘m0’ is ambiguous
    Relevant bindings include
      ex1 :: m0 Integer (bound at ContMonad.hs:3:1)
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance Monad ((->) r) -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
      instance Monad IO -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
      instance Monad [] -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
      ...plus six others
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: a <- return 1
    In the expression:
      do { a <- return 1;
           b <- return 10;
           return $ a + b }
    In an equation for ‘ex1’:
        ex1
          = do { a <- return 1;
                 b <- return 10;
                 return $ a + b }
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

How can I get this simple example to type-check?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that `ex1` as an expression works for *any* monad, and the monad used is not specified. The type of `ex1` could very well be `ex1 :: (Num b, Monad m) => m b` but, because of the [dreaded monomorphism restriction](https://wiki.haskell.org/Monomorphism_restriction), GHC cannot infer this polymorphic type and so the result is ambiguous.

You could get it to compile either by giving it an explicit type signature or disabling the monomorphism restriction:

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}
```

When you use this in GHCi, it will automatically default the value of `ex1` to `IO Int` because of the [extended default rules](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/interactive-evaluation.html#extended-default-rules):

```
*Main> ex1
11
```

These rules exist to make ghci usable as a calculator and prompt for doing IO stuff.

You should also try it with some other monads to see what happens:

```
*Main> ex1 :: [Int]
[11]
*Main> ex1 :: Maybe Int
Just 11
```

Comment: And if you actually want to use the continuation monad, you can say something like `runCont ex1 id` or even `runCont ex1 print`.